# VSCode editor.tokenColorCustomizations: Is there a way to set background colour for all HTML in a PHP document?

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

As the title says, I'd like to set my editor to put a background colour behind all HTML in a PHP document, or the other way around.

It seems like `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` would be the right vehicle, but I cannot find any examples that target large swathes of tokens like this, so not even sure if it's possible?

Comment: AFAIK, `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` allows you to set the foreground color for specific tokens but, it does not provide a direct method to set the background color.